# How would I save the state of all variables in a console application?

Tags: c#, variables, console-application

For a project that I'm working on I need to save the state of all variables in a console application.

I know that I can write individual variables to a file, but I would like to know if there is any way to do this for every variable with a value in the program.

Is this possible, and if so, how would I accomplish it?

Comment: Since console is a singleton (basically, single `main` method), you have to have yet another singleton - your, lets say, `environment` of type.. hm.. `MyEnvironment`? Either make it singleton if you'd like to go fancy, or just alloc a local variable at the begining of the `main` and mutate it appropriately to store whatever you'd like to.

Comment: Save *all the variables* automatically? No, that is not possible. You have to designate in code the specific variables you want to save, or objects that contain those variables.

Comment: save and do what with them? just json serialise the lot, add `[JsonProperty]` to each property in your main static class, game over, job done, go and get your self a coffee

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the scenario. I would create a serializable class that holds all the data to be serialized and then serialize the class to a file before exiting the application.

Then, deserialize the file (if exists) when the application starts. The class needs to be marked as `Serializable`.

```
[Serializable]
public class AppState
{
     public int Var1 { get; set; }
     public long Var2 { get; set; }
     public String Var3 { get; set; }
}
```

Then, to serialize an instance of that class as binary...

```
var state = new AppState();
state.Var1 = 4;
//TODO: populate the state object

var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

using(var stream = new FileStream("C:\\app.state", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    formatter.Serialize(stream, state);
    stream.Close();
}
```

To reload state, first make sure the file exists...

```
if(File.Exists("C:\\path_to_file")){
    //TODO: do whatever you need to here, such as deserializing the file
}
```

Then deserialize and initialize all required variables...

```
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
AppState state = null;

using(var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    state = (AppState) formatter.Deserialize(stream);
}

if(state != null){
    //TODO: initialize state
}
```

Note that there are many ways to serialize data. The most popular one are:

- JSON serialization
- XML
- Binary (as explained above)

Answer (score 0):

Use your projects `Settings` for each variable and then, use `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()` whenever you need to.

Right click your project from solution explorer > Settings.

Create a setting file if needed, then create your variables.

To use then: `Properties.Settings.Default.VariableName1;`